# jQuery UI Autocomplete: setting css of list items in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI's autocomplete module. I am using it in different places and need to alter the color of it depending on some CSS classes of the element it's attached to.

I want to do this in JavaScript and not have to write a bunch of different CSS for all the different colors. I am able to easily select and change coloring of the main autocomplete "box" I am not able to select the individual list elements and change them in JavaScript.

The following works no problem:

```
$("ul.ui-autocomplete").css("color", "white");
$(".ui-widget-content").css({"background": "transparent", "border-color": "white"});
```

But, none of these do anything:

```
$("ul.ui-autocomplete li").css("background", "red");
$("ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item").css("background", "red");
$("ul.ui-autocomplete").children().css("background", "red");
```

The annoying this is that this CSS *does* work:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete li {
    background: red;
}
```

Can anyone explain how to set the list item CSS from JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/nt1wptbw/).

```
var projects = ["apple","orange","banana","kiwi"];

$("#project").autocomplete({
    source: projects,
    messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {
            $("ul.ui-autocomplete li").css("background", "green");

        }
    },
    autoFocus: true
});
```